# I can't access Ubuntu after iwndows 11 update

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, uefi

i have two partitions on my ASUS laptop, and i was using dual booting to access windows 11 or ubuntu, however, one day windows 11 decided to update, after that, with each boot, the pc would give me a security violation alert secure boot so i disabled secure boot but still the pc directly start windows 11, i also disabled fast booting and put ubuntu partition as first option to boot but this still directly boot windows.

I'm not an expert, this is the best I know how to do for now, so I might have difficulty answering any question more complex than this, please be patient.

Any suggestions?

thank you!

Comment: Good evening Monica! You said that you "put ubuntu partition as first option to boot ". Can you tell us how you did that?